# page loads very slowly after its left idle

Tags: asp.net, html, httpwebrequest, asp.net-2.0

If the leave the webpage (any webpage) on my web application for a while (say 15 min), if I again click on another page it takes a long time to load (20 seconds)

I had a look through the google chrome --> developer module and found that, it is the web page which is the culprit here and the 'LATENCY' time for it is 17 seconds !!! and the actual 'download' time is only 117 ms.

A. what could be the cause of this issue?
B. What can I do to fix it?

thanks.

Answer (score 4):

By default in IIS, your worker processes will idle timeout after 20 minutes and have to be reloaded. This is a configurable setting.

[Here's the documentation for IIS6](http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/83b35271-c93c-49f4-b923-7fdca6fae1cf.mspx?mfr=true)

Answer (score 0):

I am quite certain that it is caused by your worker process recycling. Go to your IIS and check the application pool setting. There is a setting to say that it will automatically recycle after certain time. Either turn it off or increase it

Answer (score 0):

I can't really give you a specific answer here, as I don't know exactly what you may be doing with your application. However, ASP.NET and IIS will not keep everything your web app uses in memory forever. There are two things that could be the culprit here:

```
1) Your ASP.NET session is timing out, and you are putting something large with a lengthy load in the user session.
2) The IIS app pool is recycling after its idle timeout.
```

I think that the timeout for both of those is 20 minutes, which would roughly correspond with the 15 minutes or so you are seeing.